# asp button onclick event not firing

Tags: asp.net

asp button onclick event not firing, 
the button(id="submit") has a onclick event (Submit_Click) , which is not firing on click. why???

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="javascript:;">
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            I am a returning customer</p>
        <b>E-Mail Address:</b><br />

        <asp:TextBox name="email" runat="server" ID="email"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="email_validation" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="enter a valid email" ForeColor="Red" 
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
            ValidationGroup="email"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <b>Password:</b><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <a href="javascript:;">Forgotten Password</a><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login" 
            onclick="Submit_Click" />
        <input type="hidden" value="http://www.przemyslawlobodzinski.pl/themes/megastore/index.php?route=account/account"
            name="redirect"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't firing?  Also, what happens if you comment out the validator controls on the page?  Can you check to ensure that this HTML isn't nested inside the default `form` element that a default ASP.Net site puts on the page?

Comment: ya it is nested in a form tag, which have the property runat="server"
and if i including runat="server" in this form , getting an error like this --> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.
so what should i do ???

Comment: Remove the `form` tag you declared, just use the normal `form` tag in the Master page (or higher up in your page's dom).  With ASP.Net webforms, you don't need to add more `form` tags.

Answer (score 5):

The form is missing the `runat=server` tag.

For the asp:Button to trigger a server-side event, it needs to be in a form that has the runat="server" attribute set. This is true for all server controls. ( http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp )

Your form seems to be trying to call JavaScript instead.

Comment: i knew that !!!
but by including runat="server" , getting an error like this -->

A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Comment: That is also correct, a page ***can*** have only one server-side Form tag.  You'll need to either combine your forms into one form, OR split them into two pages.  You're bound by the limitations of how ASP.NET works, so if you've got another form on the page where the runat=server, then you need to refactor the page to work the way ASP.NET is designed.

Comment: I had a similar problem, just didn't have my buttons inside the form. Thanks. This should be the accepted answer, because this is the reason why it was not working.