# Image button rendering using code behind in c#

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to dynamically render image buttons. I need to display the below button

```
 <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImageButton3" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" OnClick="ImageButton3_click" CommandArgument='text'/>
```

The `text` is dynamically populated value. I have displayed the button as  follow

```
<input type='button' id='ImageButton3' src='Images/edit.png' >
```

in the server side. but I am not able to add the onclick  event and CommandArgument in server side.
I have to use the html tags for rendering.Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp button onclick event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902512/asp-button-onclick-event-not-firing)

Comment: What do you mean "but I am not able to add the onclick event"? What happens? what did you expect to happen?  Also better post your full form.

Comment: I have added the runat="server" attribute to input tag. and also tried by giving the onserverclick and onclick attribute to input tag but still onclick event is not firing

Comment: The duplicate question solve includes adding runat="server" to the form tag. Do you have it?